# Python & SQLite3 Selecting from two tables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have written this code in python, which I basically opens up my SQLite3 database and looks at each row in the table 'contact' and then takes each 'id' number and then looks at the matching 'id' in the table 'Users'. My problem is that it only outputs the first one and does not loop through all the rows.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor3 = conn.cursor()

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w");
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT Id, address FROM contact;") # Get address details by ID
    for row in cursor:
        ID = row[0]
        address= row[1]

        cursor2.execute("SELECT name FROM Users WHERE id= " + str(ID) + ";") # Get users's name by ID
        row2 = cursor2.fetchone()
        sendername = row2[0]

        text_file.write(firstname, lastname, address);


finally:
    conn.close()
```

Any suggestions, I'm very new to python.

Comment: Why not just ask the database to join the query?

Comment: And `file.write()` takes just one argument; you probably want to format your output as *one* string (with a newline) instead.

Comment: Why are you trying to write `firstname` and `lastname`, but your `Users` table only provides `sendername`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask the database to do a join instead:

```
cursor.execute("""\
    SELECT u.name, c.address
    FROM contact c
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = c.Id
    """)
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as outfh:
    for name, address in cursor:
        outfh.write('{} {}\n'.format(name, address)
```

The `INNER JOIN` tells SQLite to only pick rows for which there is an actual match on the `id` columns. If you marked the `id` column as a foreign key in the `contact` table, you could use a `NATURAL INNER JOIN` as well, and omit the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Users.name, contact.address FROM Users, contact WHERE contact.Id = Users.id;")
for row in cursor:
    name= row[0]
    address= row[1]
    text_file.write(name+" "+address)
```

Comment: Okay Now it outputs all the rows for the one user ID but does not output the rows for any other users.